# Getting an error while executing this python code related to the shape of the matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter

I am trying to excute this piece of pythoncode.But this is showing an error.Help me to resolve this error.

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

  data=pd.read_csv('train.csv').as_matrix()
  clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
   xtrain=data[0:21000,1:]
   train_label=data[0:21000,0]
   clf.fit(xtrain,train_label)

  xtest=data[21000:,1:]
  actual_label=data[21000:,0]

  d=xtest[8]
  d.shape(28,28)
  pt.imshow(255-d,cmap='gray')
  print(clf.predict([xtest[8]]))
  pt.show()
```

ERROR IS SHOWING LIKE THIS

```
   TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: please post the full code, so we can try to understand your problem. right now, it is incomplete. Also post the full Trace of the error

Comment: given by code @EdwinvanMierlo

Comment: could we see the complete stack trace as well please as it will often reference the line or method that is causing the specific error. Thanks

Comment: have indentation problem also

Comment: there is no error of indentation problem@Narendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in this line:

```
d.shape(28,28)
```

Just run:

```
d.shape
```

Shape is an attribute that return a tuple representing the dimensionality of the DataFrame.

If you want to change the shape use:

```
d = d.reshape(28,28)
```

Comment: again it is showing the error as TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data @Cezary.Sz

Comment: So new error is in next line, can u show what shape have 'd'?

Comment: i got the answer it should be d= d.reshape(28,28)@Cezary.Sz

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you wanted:

```
d = d.reshape(28,28)
```

`d.shape` is a tuple of the shape, and obviously can't be called with two parameters (28 and 28). Also `reshape` returns the new array, it does not reshape in place.